# Live streaming with Raspberry Pi Camera

Tags: video, raspicam

How do I stream a live video on a display screen or monitor really quickly?

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I am using this https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos and it makes things very easy. However this is a bit of a one trick pony and is not for general use like Raspbian.It isn't clear from your question wheter that matters or not.

Comment: Hey Sami – the live video problem is tricky. Not sure if you're still looking for help with this, but we built a free, low-latency (but proprietary) video streaming solution for RPi to any browser. It uses WebRTC as the framework, so it's secure and small footprint. If you're interested, the link is in my profile! Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you need to connect the Camera Module and enable it. To do this, run

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and select <kbd>Enable Camera Module</kbd>. For more information, may I suggest reading the first section of [this](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/143828902324/camera-module-part-1-getting-started) article.

To stream video from the Camera Module, we are going to use the preview function of `raspivid`. Simply type the following command:

```
raspivid -f -k
```

This will show the preview window in fullscreen (`-f`) mode. The window will not exit until you press <kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can also specify the location and size of the preview stream by using the `-p` flag:

```
raspivid -f -k -p x,y,width,height
```

For example:

```
raspivid -f -k -p 100,100,400,200
```

Comment: This does not answer the question about streaming.

Comment: This is really well written but, per previous comments, doesn't provide a means to stream the video (I'm taking the 'normal' definition of streaming, i.e. transporting over a network stream to a second device).